# C# XNA Mouse position projected to 3D plane

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

I'm working on a 3D XNA project, and I've been thinking about this problem for like 2 weeks.
So I just decided to ask you.

Basically I have a flat plane and i want to project the mouse position to that plane, but how?
I tried many ways to do it, calculated angles... 
But i figured out, that the distance must effect on the X position, maybe some math is needed what I've never heard before.

Comment: How do you represent the plane? Konrad's answer is a good point to begin with. The mouse position is actually a ray in the scene. You want to find the intersection point of that ray with your plane. Konrad's answer calculates the intersection point with the xz-plane.

Comment: Here you can watch a full source code sample doing what you want.... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axHp1f3RlHM It calculates a ray in the same way that konrad do... but the ray intersection is done with a plane object... without optimizations and easier to understand how is done.

Comment: yes, the ray thing is working, I just mixed up the Z and Y axis

Answer (score 6):

I did some code few years ago which returns the position as Vector3(x,y,z), given mouse state:

```
private Vector3 FindWhereClicked(MouseState ms)
{
    Vector3 nearScreenPoint = new Vector3(ms.X, ms.Y, 0);
    Vector3 farScreenPoint = new Vector3(ms.X, ms.Y, 1);
    Vector3 nearWorldPoint = device.Viewport.Unproject(nearScreenPoint, cam.projectionMatrix, cam.viewMatrix, Matrix.Identity);
    Vector3 farWorldPoint = device.Viewport.Unproject(farScreenPoint, cam.projectionMatrix, cam.viewMatrix, Matrix.Identity);

    Vector3 direction = farWorldPoint - nearWorldPoint;

    float zFactor = -nearWorldPoint.Y / direction.Y;
    Vector3 zeroWorldPoint = nearWorldPoint + direction * zFactor;

    return zeroWorldPoint;
}
```

- device is an instance of GraphicsDevice.

Hope it works for you.