# Moving 3d model by mouse click XNA

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

Now first of all i want to say i do know this topic exist on thi websote, but the answers to the existing questions (or question, because one of the two has no been answered) did not manage to help me.

I'm creating a game in xna, which in you look at your character from above, and move it by right clicking on the map area. The gameplay is suppose to look something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDW_jFxfYEk

I have tried to treat the map like a 2d map since i only really use 2 dimension, and yes, from various reasons, this game must be with 3D graphics, and it didnt work.

i went on and tried to implement the two solutions suggested here:
[C# XNA Mouse position projected to 3D plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503226/c-sharp-xna-mouse-position-projected-to-3d-plane)
they did not work as well.

finally i tried to use the `viewport.unproject` method to turn the mouse click into a vector3, then implementing it onto the world matrix, and you probably guess how this one turned out.

So if anyone here can please suggest me a way to do it i will be very greatful

Here's some info about my code:

BasicModel class:

```
class BasicModel
{
    public Model model { get; protected set; }
    public Matrix world = Matrix.Identity;

    public BasicModel(Model m) 
    {    
        model = m;
    }

    public virtual void Update()
    {

    }

    public void Draw(Camera camera) 
    {    
        Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];    
        model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)    
        {        
            foreach (BasicEffect be in mesh.Effects)        
            {
                be.EnableDefaultLighting(); 
                be.Projection = camera.projection; 
                be.View = camera.view; 
                be.World = GetWorld() * mesh.ParentBone.Transform;
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }

    public virtual Matrix GetWorld() 
    { 
        return world; 
    } 
}
```

And this is th ModelManager class

```
public class ModelManager : DrawableGameComponent
{
    List<BasicModel> models = new List<BasicModel>();
    Ghost thisPlayer;


    public ModelManager(Game game)
        : base(game)
    {

    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization code here
        thisPlayer = new Ghost(Color.Red, 300, new Vector3(0.05f, 0.05f, 0));
        base.Initialize();
    }


    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        models.Add(new BasicModel(Game.Content.Load<Model>(@"watcher")));
        base.LoadContent();
    } 

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) 
    {
        foreach (GhostModel bm in models) 
        { 
            bm.Draw(((Game1)Game).camera); 
        }
        base.Draw(gameTime); 
    }
}
```

They are both clean from any past solution i have tried.

Comment: These code snippets are irrelevant. Show what you have tried to calculate the point. If it is a horizontal plane, it should be quite easy because you don't even have to solve a system of equations.

Comment: If it's simple then it's all good for me since it is on horizontal plane, but me, as a beginer, still dont know how to do it. I would love if you could explane to me how to do it please.

Comment: Your second link (second answer) gives code for a horizontal plane. If you don't show your efforts and mention what's wrong with them, I don't know how I could help you.